# How to chance Code Style of Method Parentheses in Android Project using Intellij IDEA 11

Tags: coding-style, intellij-idea

In Intellij IDEA 11 Android Project, when I create the object or call the Method, it always generate the parenthese as belows:

```
TableLayout tltMain = new TableLayout(this);
tltMain.addView(txtUser);
```

How to chance the code style as belows:

```
TableLayout tltMain = new TableLayout (this);
tltMain.addView (txtUser);
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow:

`Settings -> Code Style -> Java -> Method call parenthesis`